# How to show Images In a row using repeater in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

so i have to show 9 images on my page, so I have used repeater, but the problem is that I want to show the images in a row, but in out put it shows in a column. I am working on a mobile application using qml. So can anybody suggest me how to show it in a row format using qml?

Here is my code

```
ColumnLayout {
         spacing: 10
         clip:true
         Repeater{
            model: 9
         Row{
             id:icons
             spacing:30
             Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
             Image {
                 id: img1
                 source:"path to images"
                 height: 50
                 width:50
             }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a joke but  I venture to suggest using [RowLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html) instead of  `ColumnLayout ` and remove `Row` at all.

Comment: If you are aware on the exact image paths you could perhaps store them as strings in an array `property var imageSources: ["path1", "path2", "path3"......]` and then set the image source to `imageSources` and the repeaters current index? You would then set your `model` as the `imageSources.length` also so it will only create as many as sources are there - however this is hard coded and not dynamic in which case you could take a slightly different approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `ColumnLayout` with `RowLayout` and use `modelData` property.

```
RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Repeater{
        model: ["img1.png", "img2.png"]

        Image {
            Layout.preferredWidth: 50
            Layout.preferredHeight: 50
            source: modelData
        }
    }
}
```